# Shell variable name queried from Matlab has additional character

Tags: matlab, unix

I'm working with the following script, run_test:

```
#!/bin/sh

temp=$1;
cat <<EOF | matlab

[status name] = unix('echo $temp');
disp(name);

% some Matlab code

test_complete = 1;
save(name)

exit
EOF
```

I want to pass a name to the script, run some code then save a .mat file with the name that was passed.  However, there is a curious piece of behavior:

```
[energon2] ~ $ ./run_test 'run1'
Warning: No display specified.  You will not be able to display graphics on the screen.

                            < M A T L A B (R) >
                  Copyright 1984-2010 The MathWorks, Inc.
                Version 7.12.0.635 (R2011a) 64-bit (glnxa64)
                               March 18, 2011


  To get started, type one of these: helpwin, helpdesk, or demo.
  For product information, visit www.mathworks.com.

>> >> >> >> run1

>> >> >> >> >> 
[energon2] ~ $ ls *.mat
run1?.mat
```

There is a "?" at the end of the file name when it's saved, but not when displayed on command line.  This is acceptable for my needs, but a bit irritating to not know why it's occurring.  Any explanation would be appreciated.

Edits, solution:
Yuk was correct below in the underlying cause and the use of save('$temp').  I'm now using the following script

```
#!/bin/sh

temp=$1;
cat <<EOF | matlab

% some Matlab code

test_complete = 1;
save('$temp')

exit
EOF
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: What does `getenv('temp')` give you, same results?

Comment: getenv('temp') returns an empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You `name` variable has end-of-line as the last character. When you run `echo run1` in unix this command display `run1` and then "hit enter". In your script all the output of echo are saved to the `name variable`.

You can confirm it with the following:

```
>> format compact
>> [status, name] = unix('echo run1')
status =
     0
name =
run1

>> numel(name)
ans =
     5
>> int8(name(end))
ans =
   10
>> int8(sprintf('\n'))
ans =
   10
```

Apparently this character can be a part of a file name in unix, but shell displays it as `?`.

Can't you do `save($temp)` instead?

**EDIT**: *See my comments below for correction and more explanation.*

Comment: save($temp) throws an error and insists that save must receive a string.

Comment: How about `save $temp` or `save('$temp')`?

Comment: They both work.  I didn't know Matlab had direct access to shell variables.  Thank you.

Comment: In your case MATLAB does not access shell variable. It's the shell that substitute `$temp` with its value before passing commands to MATLAB. You are not using MATLAB script, but shell script. So even in `[status name] = unix('echo $temp');` MATLAB sees it as `[status name] = unix('echo run1');`. On the other hand, `$temp` defined only in the script, not in the main environment, this is why `getenv('temp')` does not return anything.